# Rails Simple_form (nested) - duplicate entries on save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am using Rails 5 and simple form to build an app. I'm trying to have each nested model display its fields in a different tab or column using Twitter Bootstrap. I now have this case, where when creating a new or editing/updating an existing parent record (here "document type", the existing records of the nested model (here "keywords") get duplicated. Deletion using :_destroy does not function either.

I am able to create and delete separately. Now looking to add it to the parent and allow edit. It is something I would be using much more. be great to get it to work. How does this come / to fix it?

These are my models:

```
class Documenttype < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :annotations, dependent: :restrict_with_error
    has_many :documents, dependent: :restrict_with_error
    has_many :tagtypes, dependent: :restrict_with_error
    has_many :keywords, dependent: :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :keywords, allow_destroy: true

    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
    scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }
end

class Keyword < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :documenttype

  validates :keywords, presence: true
  validates :language, presence: true
end
```

this is the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @documenttype,  html: { class: 'form-horizontal', multipart: true },
    wrapper: :horizontal_form,
    wrapper_mappings: {
        check_boxes: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
        radio_buttons: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
        boolean: :horizontal_boolean
    } do |f| %>

    <div class="btn-toolbar btn-group" role="toolbar">
      <%= f.button :submit, :class => "btn btn-xs btn-default" %> <%= link_to 'List' , documenttypes_path, :class => "btn btn-xs btn-default" %>
    </div>

    <h4>Document Type</h4>

   <div class="col-md-6">

    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <%= f.input :name, placeholder: 'Enter name' %>

    <%= f.input :description, placeholder: 'Description' %>

    <%= f.input :active, as: :boolean %>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :keywords do |ff| %>
      <div class="panel panel-body panel-default">
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <%= ff.input :language, :collection => ["NL","EN"], :label => false %> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
        <%= ff.input :keywords, placeholder: 'add keywords separated by " ; " - example: document number; document date' %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
        <%= ff.check_box :_destroy, label: "del"%>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end -%>
    </div>
    <% end -%>
```

Comment: looks like I found what I need to add `:_destroy` to strongparams and consider validations on the nested model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learning from this issue:

- to destroy nested records, ensure that (besides `:id`) also `:_destroy` is added to strongparams
- to use validations for nested fields, use `accepts_nested_attributes_for :keywords, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :something_to_check`